# How to get audio file from Android SpeechRecognizer in OnRecgonitionListener method

Tags: android, android-intent, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

Hi how to get recorded audio file in speecRecognizer is RecognitionListener methods. I use recognizer intent but not this option.

speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);

```
    speechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);

    Log.e("vbvb", "Locale: "+Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());

    speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "az-AZ");
    //speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.GET_AUDIO_FORMAT", "audio/AMR");
    //speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.GET_AUDIO", true);


 @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle results) {
            ArrayList<String> matches = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);

            if(matches != null) {
                String result = matches.get(0);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                //Uri audioUri = speechRecognizerIntent.getData();

                sendApiRequest(result);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: any update on this?